# Find Non-UTF8 Filenames on Linux File System

Tags: regex, linux, find, grep

I have a number of files hiding in my LANG=en_US:UTF-8 filesystem that have been uploaded with unrecognisable characters in their filename.

I need to search the filesystem and return all filenames that have at least one character that is not in the standard range (a-zA-Z0-9 and .-_ etc.)

I have been trying to following but no luck.

```
find . | egrep [^a-zA-Z0-9_\.\/\-\s]
```

I'm using Fedora Code 9.

Comment: Why should they only allow those characters? Others are perfectly fine as well, as long as they are correctly encoded

Answer (score 17):

[`convmv`](http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/) might be interesting to you. It doesn't just find those files, but also supports renaming them to correct file names (if it can guess what went wrong).

Comment: I had 1000+ files with Windows 1252 encoding and lots of umlauts. "convmv -r -f cp1252 -t utf8 --notest ." worked for me. Didn't know there was such a program. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
find . | perl -ne 'print if /[^[:ascii:]]/'
```

Comment: if something is not ascii it doesn't men it is not utf.

Comment: Example:  

    `emil@galeon:/tmp/expermients$ ls`  
    `laka.txt  łąka.txt`  
    `emil@galeon:/tmp/expermients$ find . | perl -ane '{ if(m/[[:^ascii:]]/) { print } }'  
    `./łąka.txt`  

And "łąka.txt" is proper utf8 encoded name.

Answer (score 2):

> find . | egrep [^a-zA-Z0-9_./-\s]

Danger, shell escaping!

bash will be interpreting that last parameter, removing one level of backslash-escaping. Try putting double quotes around the "[^group]" expression.

Also of course this disallows a lot more than UTF-8. It is [possible](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-forms-utf-8) to construct a regex to match valid UTF-8 strings, but it's rather ugly. If you have Python 2.x available you could take advantage of that:

```
import os.path
def walk(dir):
    for child in os.listdir(dir):
        child= os.path.join(dir, child)
        if os.path.isdir(child):
            for descendant in walk(child):
                yield descendant
        yield child

for path in walk('.'):
    try:
        u= unicode(path, 'utf-8')
    except UnicodeError:
        # print path, or attempt to rename file
```

Comment: Single quotes would be better, in that context.

Comment: If this disallows UTF-8, isn't it completely useless for OP's request? They're trying to disallow *non* UTF-8 filenames.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem to the OP for which I was given a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360151/using-find-or-grep-to-locate-filenames-with-accented-characters-from-a-different/4362626#4362626) on Superuser (see also [further comments](https://superuser.com/questions/218825/using-find-or-grep-to-locate-filenames-with-accented-characters-from-a-different/218831#218831)) that I found more satisfactory than the "convmv solution", although I appreciate to have discovered comvmv too.

Comment: You should always write the solution in your answer, don't simply link to it. I think you're referring to `LANG=C find . -regex '.*[^a-zA-Z./-].*'` which IMHO isn't great since it will "detect" any filename that contains a space, a number, an underscore, or an ASCII symbol (like a $).